# Multiple url in $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, route-provider

I want to redirect multiple url for $routeProvider. How can I apply this? For example, I am trying like this,

```
.when('/laptop' || '/mobile', {
     templateUrl: '/Selection_Routing/Selection_Product/ProductDetails.html',
     controller: 'ProductDetailsController'
     })
```

Please note that I want to redirect either /laptop or /mobile url, but it is not working. Any suggestion?

Comment: There is an issue opened for this but the Ng team does not reply since 2014. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9041

Comment: I am wondering If I have 100 pages !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do something similar with UI Router.

```
var sameURL = "laptop,mobile,foo,bar".split(",");
angular.forEach(sameURL function(route) {
     .state(route, {
          url: "/" + route,
          templateUrl: "views/home.html"
      })
})
```

You should be able to adapt this easily.