# Can when function of routeProvider take multiple url paths?

Tags: angularjs

my code its something like this:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
        })
        .when('/login', {
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

But I wonder if it could be something like this: 
...

```
    .when('/login' OR '/' OR '/SOMETHING', {
        controller: 'LoginController',
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
    })
```

...

I already read [doc of when function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) and a have see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37284707/multiple-url-in-routeprovider) too, but unfortunately I have not be able to find a conclusive answer.

Can when function of routeProvider take multiple url paths? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine.Can you just guide me which error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting and error. I am just searching for an answer to this question: Can when function of routeProvider take multiple url paths?.
Because I do not want to repeat code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reuse the data you can simply:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    loginData = {
      controller: 'LoginController',
      templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
    };

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', loginData)
        .when('/login', loginData)
        …
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

Comment: I will not mark like ACCEPTED, because this does not answer to my question directly. I do not try yet, but seems like a good/better solution. Thank you!

Comment: @GonçaloBorges No worries. The [API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) indicates that `path` must be a string so I don't think you'll find any alternatives.